# Форматированный вывод Version

Tags: c#, форматирование, формат

Имеется экземпляр [Version](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.version?view=netframework-4.8), который необходимо приводить к определённому текстовому формату. Например Version `12.3.4.0` должно приводится к `12.03.04.00`. На данный момент делаю так:

```cs
public static string ToD2Format(this Version version)
{
    return version.Major.ToString("D2") + "."
        + version.Minor.ToString("D2") + "."
        + version.Build.ToString("D2") + "."
        + version.Revision.ToString("D2");
}
```

Но так сложилось, что в различных частях кодовой базы используются разные форматы.  Поэтому возник вопрос: можно ли каким-либо образом (в идеале элегантным) задавать строковой формат (к примеру так-же, как и при составном форматировании)?

```cs
// вместо version.ToD2Format();
version.FormatTo("{0}.{1:D2}.{2:D2}.{3:D2}");
```

---

#### Ссылки по теме

- [Класс Version](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.version?view=netframework-4.8)
- [Строки настраиваемых числовых форматов](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings?view=netframework-4.8)
- [Составное форматирование](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/base-types/composite-formatting)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил так:

```cs
public static string FormatTo(this Version version, string format)
{
    return string.Format(format, new object[] {
        version.Major,
        version.Minor,
        version.Build,
        version.Revision,
        version.MajorRevision,
        version.MinorRevision
    });
}
```